# Pool NeuraChlDS is Suspended, cannot allocate resources to applications in weblogic server 11g 10.3.6

Tags: oracle11g

iam using weblogic server 10.3.6server with 1 admin,1 managed server....no clustering applied here....we have an error of Cannot obtain XAConnection weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDisabledException: Pool NeuraChlDS is Suspended, cannot allocate resources to applications''
what does it means..is it indicates high sys or cpu usability? what are steps we have to overcome this ERROR

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are out of physical connections. Or your application is not releasing connections that are not in use anymore, or it needs more connections. In that case you can enlarge Maximum capacity value in console.
"Services-> Data Sources -> your data source -> Connection Pool -> Maximum Capacity"

Answer (score 0):

I received this same 'ResourceDisabledException: Pool is suspended' error in my environment. The error message I received right before the ResourceDisabledException was a PoolDisabledSQLException. Oracle gives some information about when WLS throws a PoolDisabledSQLException here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13737/jdbc_datasources.htm#JDBCA180

In my case, the connection pool was trying to grow to meet demand and received 2 failures (socket read timed out) trying to create a connection to the database.  After the second failure, WLS disabled the entire connection pool because it decided that the connectivity to the database was questionable.  After a period of time, it re-enabled the pool. Along with some new alerting, we're planning to set our initial connections to the same value as the max connections for our connection pools to minimize this issue in the future. We're still looking into why we received those initial socket read timed out errors.